# Search in my own website

Tags: search, web

I am new in HTML and CSS and I have a question regarding the search functionality in my own built website. I have put the search box by using  but how can I make this work? For example I have a "Blog" section and I want the search to be performed in this part of the website.

It is a small personal website for professional purposes.

Thank you in advance!
Michail

Comment: You need server-side code.  (or a service like https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2630969)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would use a server sided language like PHP:

PHP Site

With this you can search an SQL Database and have direct links to your blog pages

Answer (score 0):

That would require a bit of coding experience. For now I would recommend using a service like Swiftype to crawl your site and index searchable pages.

https://swiftype.com

Comment: That's an option I didn't know!Thank you very much for your response!